# how to get Store JAXBelement to String?

Tags: java, jsp, jaxbelement

Hello I want to Store JAXBelement value to String variable how to do this kindly tell me please.
I have Following method .

```
public JAXBElement<String> getSessionId()
 {
    return sessionId;
}
```

above method is in sessiondata class. i have create object of sessiodata class like below.

```
 sessiondata result=new sessiondata();
```

i have call getsession method of sessiondata class like below.

```
result.getssionId();
```

now i want to store sessionid in to string variable. but its type is JAXBelment  now tell me how to store in to String.

now i want to store sessionId to One String variable. and pass in to another method. kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

String sID = (String)result.getSessionId().getValue();

Comment: this Give me error like cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getSessionId()
  location: class SimplifiedJSPServlet

Comment: That means, that your compilator can't find method getSessionId() in class SimplifiedJSPServlet not in sessiondata class. Try to localize the error in your source file.

Comment: i got the ans, String Sid=result.getSessionId().toString();